# How to register a block on minecraft 1.11 forge

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I have created a class for the block called 'BlockTest.java' that extends the minecraft TNT block and just overrides the onBlockActivated function. The problem is how to register the block, The only tutorials I can find are for earlier versions.

I believe that for every block you need an ItemBlock as well. This is what my attempt at registering currently looks like:

```
//(this code is in my main class inside init)
public static Block oldTNT;
public static ItemBlock oldTNTIB;

oldTNT = new blockTest();
oldTNT.setRegistryName("oldTNT");
oldTNT.setUnlocalizedName(oldTNT.getRegistryName().toString());
GameRegistry.register(oldTNT);

oldTNTIB.setRegistryName("oldTNT");
oldTNTIB.setUnlocalizedName(oldTNTIB.getRegistryName().toString());
GameRegistry.register(oldTNTIB);
```

But this is crashing the game and telling me the problem was in the registering stage. Is this along the right lines at all? Do I need to instantiate the itemBlock as well?

bonus question, I assume things like setting the creative tab are done where I have set the unlocalised name?

Please be nice as I'm new to mod development, any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to instantiate the ItemBlock. This is one way:

```
oldTNTIB = new ItemBlock(oldTNT);
```

For setting the creative tab, you can use:

```
oldTNT.setCreativeTab(<enter tab here>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same registry name `oldTNT` for two blocks (`oldTNT` and `oldTNTIB`) which will cause a crash.

You need to change the registry name for the second block to something different from the first block's registry name.

Additionally, it's highly recommended that, in 1.11+, you use all lowercase letters for things like registry names. This is because in 1.11+ Minecraft's resource pack system forces lowercasing on `ResourceLocation`s. If you use capital letters in things like registry names, this can cause confusion later on.

For setting the creative tab, you just call `setCreativeTab` on your block instance with the appropriate `CreativeTabs` instance (all the vanilla Minecraft tabs have static fields in the `CreativeTabs` class).